# Возникает ошибка net.pipe

Tags: asp.net

Есть сервер 2012R2. Работает IIS.
При обращении к одному из сервисов возникает ошибка вида:

> ***An error occurred while executing the rule:The message could not be dispatched because the service at the endpoint address 'net.pipe://localhost/XXX.svc' is unavailable for the protocol of the address***

И при этом останавливается пул в котором сайт зарегестрирован.
в `Advanced Settings net.pipe` присутствует.
`Net.pipe listener Adapter` запущен.
Исходников нет к сожалению.

Вопрос: Проблема с этим сервисом или с какими-то настройками?
Есть ли иструмент (по типу `Fiddler`, но для `net.pipe`) для отслеживания запросов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка заключалась в том, что учетке, под которой работал пул, не были назначены права в системе. Добавил в админы - все заработало!